# protected question requires >=10

Tags: bug, status-completed

> protected by XXX
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned **more than 10 reputation** on this site.

Can this text be changed to **at least** (non-strict inequality)? As far as I know this is the case.

Comment: It used to be 15. I guess you can get one upvote and accept an answer to one of your questions now, as opposed to getting one upvote on a question and one upvote on an answer. I'd rather see two positive actions instead of just one.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I feel a little bit lost here...what exactly is the difference here? It's two ways to say the same thing, but what renders it different here? Politeness?

Comment: @Bobby "at least 10" includes 10; "more than 10" means a minimum of 11

Comment: Bobby: If you have exactly 10 reputation, then you have at least 10, but not more than 10 (i.e. >=10 but not >10). I know the difference is small and useless as most people gain quickly reputation, but as a mathematician/programmer I have OCD about such details. Personally I think the requirement could be bit higher, say 30.

Comment: @Bobby: "Non-strict equality" means that the user would need just 10 rep. It's probably a moot point anyway, since every new user gets 1 rep free, and one upvote on an answer gives them 11 rep.  So all we're talking about here is pedantry about the wording.

Comment: @sdcvvc: I'd actually place it as high as the required comment-everywhere rep.

Comment: Even though it's wrong I'll miss the old wording.  Farewell, more than.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This text will be updated after our next deploy later today.